# How to integrate $\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{dz}{z(z-i)}$ with $\gamma_1 = Re^{it}$, $R>1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am stuck calculating the integral
$$\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{dz}{z(z-i)}$$ over $\gamma_1 = Re^{it}, R>1$.

If I had to integrate over $\gamma_2 = re^{it}, r < 1$, I could just expand the integrand into a power series (using the geometric series) around $z=0$, but with $R>1$ this approach won't work. I quite frankly don't have any other idea on how to approach this.

Any hints?

Comment: The [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) is unavailable to you I take it?

Comment: Use partial fractions and then use the geometric series expansion on both of them, if you're really that averse to using the residue theorem.

Comment: He didn't say "homework" so why would the Residue Theorem be off-limits?

Comment: The appropriate geometric series in this case is in powers of $1/R$.

Comment: Yes, residue theorem is off-limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer here is to use the residue theorem. I assume because you are asking this question, you have not yet learned about it.

Instead, you could note $\frac{1}{z(z-i)}=i(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z-i})$. The $\frac{1}{z}$ term you can integrate directly. For the other term, note that on this contour we have $|z|>|i|$, so $1>|i/z|$. Then we can write the second term as $\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-i/z}=\frac{1}{z}(1+i/z+(i/z)^2+...)$. You can then multiply out and integrate term by term.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually tried using partial fraction decomposition, but was too dumb to note $|\frac{i}{z}|<1$. :)